# Date format is failing in php query using informix (SQL-based)

Tags: php, sql, date, informix

I'm running a service which (should) returns a json with a response from a sql query to fill a table. For debugging purposes i've added the resulting query string to the response to try it directly on the database and the query works in my database. 
Actually im getting the following errors when i run it from my service and i need to solve this:

> Invalid year in date. When i go for "and table.datefield >=
>   '".$date."'
>
> Invalid month in date. When using  "and table.datefield >=
>   {d'".$date."'}

Both with HY000 error code. (Description below)

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -1204 [Informix][Informix ODBC
>   Driver][Informix]Invalid year in date (SQLPrepare[-1204] at
>   /usr/PRODUCTO/apache_jano/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.3/informix_driver.c:131)
>   ISAM: 264
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -1205 [Informix][Informix ODBC
>   Driver][Informix]Invalid month in date (SQLPrepare[-1205] at
>   /usr/PRODUCTO/apache_jano/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.3/informix_driver.c:131)
>   ISAM: 264

At some point the 2nd option from above worked (it detects the year so i think its the closest approach), but it doesnt anymore. I can't either find the place where i found the {d } documentation so (which solved it in the past), any link would also be appreciated. 
One more thing i cant use bind_params for this (I've been explicitly told to do it without this).

This is part which is failing (deleting this condition in my query works perfect)

SQL code condition which works in dbeaver and taken from response string:

```
 AND (

(table.fecha_inicial <= { d '2018-07-15' }AND (table.fecha_final >= { d '2019-07-15' }OR table.fecha_final IS NULL))

OR 

(table.fecha_inicial >= { d '2018-07-15' }AND (table.fecha_final <= { d '2019-07-15' } OR table.fecha_final IS NULL)))
```

PHP coding

```
    if ($fechaInicio){ $fechaInicio = date('Y-m-d',     strtotime($fechaInicio));}
    if ($fechaFin){ $fechaFin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fechaFin));}
    $cond_fechas = " AND ( (table.fecha_inicial     <= '".$fechaInicio."' AND (table.fecha_final >= {d'".$fechaFin."'}     OR table.fecha_final IS NULL)) "
                    . " OR (table.fecha_inicial     >= '".$fechaInicio."' AND (table.fecha_final <= {d'".$fechaFin."'}     OR table.fecha_final IS NULL)))";


 $result['query'] = $query;
 $conn = DB::getConnection('bbdd');
 $result['das']= $conn->preparedQuery($query);

if (isset($result['das'])) {
   return JwtCheckHeader::json($result['das']);
} else {
   return JwtCheckHeader::json($result);
}
```

Comment: The `{ d }` notation is from `Escape Sequences in ODBC` which also seem to apply to jdbc (and that is why they work in `dbeaver`). You need to find out what is the date format that your service environment is using.

Comment: The format should be YYYY-mm-dd (2019-01-16) or as i formatted it in php with  date ('Y-m-d' ). I see it visually that way on the database. Can that be different from the way i see?. It seems to lose format or not take it correctly but dunno why. 
Feel free to put your comment as an answer, since it gives me a tip to follow on the research for the {d} comment. Which i really apreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the issue here. 
It should return some error of "no results matching your conditions" instead of the "format_error" which mislead me completely.

This error happened when comparing some of the db empty date strings in database with the dates provided.

It fails when no data meets and success when the dates provided meet requirements, so it works!
Hope it will help somebody else in the future.

Comment: Whoever forbade parameterized queries should be fired. That's like saying "do this stunt, but don't use a safety belt"

Comment: Another team is going to set that filtering in some "corporate way". But in the meantime they told me to make it work without it.

Comment: I've been in this industry 15 years now. It's always been a bad idea. It ruins performance by smashing the query plan cache (not just your query, it ruins other query's performance too). It makes the code more fragile, less testable, less secure (sql injection attacks), etc, etc. Nothing is worth all those down sides.

Comment: I've learnt from all my previous jobs not to oppose THE BOSS even if he is wrong. But i gave him the same suggestion you did :D